# How to use io primitives (seek, read) on file stream that may be in universal mode?

Tags: python, file-io, io

I have a `file` object which may or may not be open in universal mode.  (I can access this mode with `file.mode`, if that helps).

I want to deal with this file using the standard `io` methods: `read` and `seek`.

If I open the file in non-universal mode, everything works nicely:

```
In [1]: f = open('example', 'r')

In [2]: f.read()
Out[2]: 'Line1\r\nLine2\r\n' # uhoh, this file has carriage returns

In [3]: f.seek(0)

In [4]: f.read(8)
Out[4]: 'Line1\r\nL'

In [5]: f.seek(-8, 1)

In [6]: f.read(8)
Out[6]: 'Line1\r\nL' # as expected, this is the same as before

In [7]: f.close()
```

However, if I open the file in universal mode, we have a problem:

```
In [8]: f = open('example', 'rU')

In [9]: f.read()
Out[9]: 'Line1\nLine2\n' # no carriage returns - thanks, 'U'!

In [10]: f.seek(0)

In [11]: f.read(8)
Out[11]: 'Line1\nLi'

In [12]: f.seek(-8, 1)

In [13]: f.read(8)
Out[13]: 'ine1\nLin' # NOT the same output, as what we read as '\n' was *2* bytes
```

Python interprets the `\r\n` as a `\n`, and returns a string of length 8.

However, creating this string involved reading *9 bytes* from the file.

As a result, when trying to reverse the `read` using `seek`, we don't get back to where we started!

---

Is there a way to identify that we consumed a 2-byte newline or, better yet, disable this behaviour?

The best I can come up with at the moment is to do a `tell` before and after the read, and check how much we *actually* got, but that seems incredibly inelegant.

---

As an aside, it seems to me that this behaviour is actually contrary to the documentation of `read`:

```
In [54]: f.read?
Type:       builtin_function_or_method
String Form:<built-in method read of file object at 0x1a35f60>
Docstring:
read([size]) -> read at most size bytes, returned as a string.

If the size argument is negative or omitted, read until EOF is reached.
Notice that when in non-blocking mode, less data than what was requested
may be returned, even if no size parameter was given.
```

To my reading, that suggests that at most size bytes should be *read*, not *returned*.

In particular, I believe that the correct semantics of the above example should be:

```
In [11]: f.read(8)
Out[11]: 'Line1\nL' # return a string of length *7*
```

Am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: Text-mode I/O was created by the devil to foil the schemes of humankind.  Avoid it like the plague.

Comment: What you ask isn't possible. Just open the file in binary mode and work with that. Or use `io.open(..., newline='\n')` to disable universal newlines.

Answer (score 1):

What are you really trying to do?

If your reason for reading forwards and then seeking backwards is that you want to return to a particular point in the file, then use tell() to record where you are. That's easier than keeping track of how many bytes you read.

```
savepos = f.tell()
f.read(8)
f.seek(savepos)
f.read(8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm listing a workaround here in an answer, although I am by no means satisfied.

Given that the underlying problem is the discrepancy between the length of a `\n` in universal mode, and the number of bytes it actually represents in the file, one way to avoid the error is to read from an intermediate stream for which `\n` actually does represent one byte:

```
def wrap_stream(f):
    # if this stream is a file, it's possible to just throw the contents in
    # another stream
    # alternatively, we could implement an io object which used a generator to
    # read lines from f and interpose newlines as required
    return StringIO(f.read())
```

The new `io` object returned from `wrap_stream` will show newlines as `\n`, no matter what mode the file was opened in.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to use fdopen to get a new file object on the existing descriptor, but without the offending 'U' mode, and use that for seeking? For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> f=open('example','rU')
>>> f.read()
'Line1\nLine2\n'
>>> ff=os.fdopen(f.fileno(),'r')
>>> ff.seek(0)
>>> ff.read()
'Line1\r\nLine2\r\n'
>>> ff.seek(-7,1)
>>> f.read()
'Line2\n'
>>>
```

So you can have the file in whatever mode works for you without having to close it and reopen it in that mode.